# Auto-layout constraints for landscape/portrait on 3.5 & 4 inch forms. UIImageview UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, autolayout

Using XCode 4.6 and trying put a single `UIImageView` and single `UITextView` on an iPhone screen for both 3.5 & 4 inch form factors rotatable between landscape or portrait.

For Portrait I'd like the UIImageView to be at the top of the screen. 
Aspect ratio fixed. About 1/2 of the screen size. 
The bottom half filled with the UITextView.

For Landscape UIImageView on the right and text on the left. 
33/66 split in size. Image is of ratio 100W/175H

I thought this would be easy, but it's driving me nuts.

Has anyone found a good method to working out the constraints for a "simple" view like this which works?

Any good tutorials or has someone else done something similar, figured it out and would care to share?

Starting to see the difference in XCode between the "mature" features and the "green" ones. Autolayout is definitely in the latter.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate anything about how you want these views to be arranged, nor how you want layout to adapt to different screen sizes and orientations; this makes it difficult to provide a useful answer. For general autolayout help, I'd recommend watching the [videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos) from WWDC 2012 (and 2011; that year it only existed for Mac OS, not iOS, but the system works the same on both platforms).

Answer (score -1):

I made a class called ScreenSize Helper. Not ideal but works and gives me pixel level control.

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

            someRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);


            if ([NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds])isEqualToString:@"{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}"]) {
                NSLog(@"iPhone 5");

                iphone5Rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

            }
            else {
                 NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
                deviceNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];

               iphone4Rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
            }
        }
        else {
            //For iPad Sizes
            someRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 680, 680);

        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I've done this for another section which I have over 30 different possible view arrangements. For the Image/Text screen i thought the auto layout would be straight forward. It's not.